# How to implement back button in angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9

I'm implementing a small project with only two UIs.

1-The first UI is called Home which contains paginated users list `the home component`.

2-The second UI is called user details which contains user profile `the user-details component`

3- and of course the app component which contains the tool bar and `router-outlet`

let us suppose the following scenario

I'm in the `home` UI and in the second page of the paginated users list and I clicked on one of the users item then the `user-details` UI appeard and I'm now in the second UI and I now I want to navigate back to the home but when doing so the `home` UI is recreated and become the first page of the users list instead of the second page where we left it because this is my code of the back button

```
<img
  routerLink = "/home" style="cursor: pointer;"
    width="40"
    alt="Angular Logo"
 />
  <span routerLink = "/home" style="cursor: pointer;">Users</span>
```

my question is:
is there is any way to implement it in such a way it doesn't recreate the home page `i.e.` implement the correct behavior of back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways that you can approach this.

If you're using a pagination library (such as ngx-pagination), then hopefully the pagination component takes an input for the current page. You'd then need to keep track of that page either through a service or in persistent storage.
Whenever you route back to the Home UI, get the page that you were on and load that back into the pagination component.

Another way can be to use router parameters. By modifying your urls a bit, they can take on the following form:

- `/home/1`
- `/home/2`
- `/home/3`

Clicking on a user in page 2 can give the url: `/home/2/user-id` (just an example)

The path for your home component can look like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "home/:pageNumber", component: HomeComponent }
];
```

Upon loading the home component, you can get the get the router parameter as follows (I'm using the Router method but you can parse the URL manually as well):

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    const pageNumber = this.router.navigationExtras.params['pageNumber'];
  }
}
```

You can then load this page number into your pagination component. Using this method doesn't require you to keep track of the previous pages.

There are probably better methods to do this, but this is just some suggestions :)